# Bizarre domain/host file/browser issues. A real chin-scratcher

Tags: browser, hosts-file, browser-cache, bindings

I was working on a dev site yesterday (of which I have a modified host file to view) when all of the sudden Chrome stopped being able to load the site. Or the production site (no host file mods necessary) or any other site on either server. Odd, so I move from the Mac to the PC to see if they worked over there. Yup, work just fine. So I ask my co-worker with the same model Mac to see if they work for her. Yep, work for her as well.

None work in FireFox either. So I flush all browser cache and `$ dscacheutil -flushcache`. Still nothing. Double-check the host file, move the entry from the bottom to the top for good measure and re-save. Nada.

Then I tried to TS into the servers and am able to reach *both* servers. WTF? I can SFTP into all of them AND SVN as well, but still nothing on the browsers. I rebooted my machine. Still nothing.

Then I think maybe... just maybe my public IP has been blacklisted by the firewall. As a last ditch effort I try Safari, and ***all sites work on Safari!***. What. The. Hell. Is. Going. On. ?

Prior to losing connections on Chrome I hadn't accessed any of the dev sites on firefox. I had literally modified my host file for this dev site yesterday morning. I'm stumped. Is there a category for gremlins? Because I'm pretty sure they are to blame.

****EDIT****

One site on each server loaded for me in Safari exactly once. And then refuse to load again. Server is not responding, it says.

Comment: A firewall failover fixed it, so I guess my suspicions were correct... still doesn't explain why it would let a new browser from the same IP connect, though. Thanks to anyone who considered responding :)

Comment: You should, now that a couple hours have passed, add a quick answer to your own question and mark it as the solution. Knowing this is a symptom of firewall woes might help the next guy.

Comment: Ah thanks. On other forums it shows up right away... i just figured my rep was too low to do that.

Comment: Proxy on the network anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A firewall failover fixed it, so I guess my suspicions were correct... still doesn't explain why it would let a new browser from the same IP connect, though. Stupid firewall.